# Unsupported argument .An argument named “subnet_id” is not expected here

Tags: terraform

Application Gateway ingress controller is added for aks in terraform file.After adding showing the above error.
My module in azure is below

Cluster Resource Group

```
resource “azurerm_resource_group” “aks” {

name = var.resource_group_name

location = var.location

}
```

AKS Cluster Network

```
module “aks_network” {

source = “…/modules/aks_network”

subnet_name = var.subnet_name

vnet_name = var.vnet_name

name = azurerm_resource_group.aks.name

subnet_cidr = var.subnet_cidr

location = var.location

address_space = var.address_space

app_gateway_subnet_name = var.app_gateway_subnet_name

app_gateway_subnet_address_prefix = var.app_gateway_subnet_address_prefix

}
```

AKS Log Analytics

```
module “log_analytics” {

source = “…/modules/log_analytics”

name = azurerm_resource_group.aks.name

log_analytics_workspace_location = var.log_analytics_workspace_location

log_analytics_workspace_name = var.log_analytics_workspace_name

log_analytics_workspace_sku = var.log_analytics_workspace_sku

}
```

AKS Cluster

```
module “aks_cluster” {

source = “…/modules/aks-cluster”

cluster_name = var.cluster_name

location = var.location

dns_prefix = var.dns_prefix

name = azurerm_resource_group.aks.name

kubernetes_version = var.kubernetes_version

node_count = var.node_count

min_count = var.min_count

max_count = var.max_count

vm_size = var.vm_size

service_cidr = var.service_cidr

network_plugin = var.network_plugin

vnet_subnet_id = module.aks_network.aks_subnet_id

client_id = var.client_id

client_secret = var.client_secret

environment = var.environment

subnet_id = module.aks_network.subnet_app_gateway_id

}
```

and below are the variable file for the above module

variables.tf

```
variable “client_id” {

description = “Azure Service Principal id (client id)”

}

variable “client_secret” {

description = “Azure client Service Principal secret (client secret)”

}

variable resource_group_name {

description = “Resource Group name”

}

variable “node_count” {

description = “number of nodes to deploy”

}

variable “dns_prefix” {

description = “DNS Suffix”

}

variable cluster_name {

description = “AKS cluster name”

}

variable location {

description = “azure location to deploy resources”

}

variable log_analytics_workspace_name {

description = “azure name to deploy log analytics workspace”

}

variable log_analytics_workspace_location {

description = “azure location to deploy log analytics workspace”

}

variable log_analytics_workspace_sku {

description = “azure sku to deploy log analytics workspace”

}

variable subnet_name {

description = “subnet id where the nodes will be deployed”

}

variable vnet_name {

description = “vnet id where the nodes will be deployed”

}

variable subnet_cidr {

description = “the subnet cidr range”

}

variable kubernetes_version {

description = “version of the kubernetes cluster”

}

variable “vm_size” {

description = “size/type of VM to use for nodes”

}

variable “service_cidr” {

description = “size/type of VM to use for nodes”

}

variable “network_plugin” {

description = “size/type of VM to use for nodes”

}

variable “address_space” {

description = “The address space that is used the virtual network”

}

variable “min_count” {

description = “Minimum Node Count”

}

variable “max_count” {

description = “Maximum Node Count”

}

variable “environment” {

description = “Environment”

}

variable “app_gateway_subnet_name” {

description = “App Gateway Subnet Name”

}

variable “app_gateway_subnet_address_prefix” {

description = “App Gateway Subnet Address Prefix”

}
```

aks_network

main.tf is as below

```
resource “azurerm_virtual_network” “aks_vnet” {

name = var.vnet_name

address_space = [var.address_space]

resource_group_name = var.name

location = var.location

}

resource “azurerm_subnet” “aks_subnet” {

name = var.subnet_name

resource_group_name = var.name

virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.aks_vnet.name

address_prefix = var.subnet_cidr

}

resource “azurerm_subnet” “subnet_app_gateway” {

resource_group_name = var.name

virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.aks_vnet.name

name = var.app_gateway_subnet_name

address_prefix = var.app_gateway_subnet_address_prefix

}
```

variables.tf

```
variable “subnet_name” {

description = “name to give the subnet”

}

variable “name” {

description = “resource group that the vnet resides in”

}

variable “vnet_name” {

description = “name of the vnet that this subnet will belong to”

}

variable “subnet_cidr” {

description = “the subnet cidr range”

}

variable “location” {

description = “the cluster location”

}

variable “address_space” {

description = “Network address space”

}

variable “app_gateway_subnet_name” {

description = “App Gateway Subnet Name.”

default = “agw-subnet”

}

variable “app_gateway_subnet_address_prefix” {

description = “Containers DNS server IP address.”

default = “10.100.0.0/24”

}
```

aks-cluster
main.tf

```
resource “azurerm_kubernetes_cluster” “cluster” {

name = var.cluster_name

location = var.location

resource_group_name = var.name

dns_prefix = var.dns_prefix

kubernetes_version = var.kubernetes_version

default_node_pool {

name            = var.default_pool_name

node_count      = var.node_count

vm_size         = var.vm_size

vnet_subnet_id  = var.vnet_subnet_id

type            = var.default_pool_type

enable_auto_scaling = true

min_count           = var.min_count

max_count           = var.max_count
}

addon_profile {

azure_policy {

  enabled = true  

}

ingress_application_gateway {

  enabled = true

  subnet_id = resource.azurerm_subnet.subnet_app_gateway.id

}
}

role_based_access_control {

enabled = true
}

network_profile {

network_plugin     = var.network_plugin

network_policy     = "azure"

service_cidr       = var.service_cidr

dns_service_ip     = "10.0.0.10"

docker_bridge_cidr = "172.17.0.1/16"
}

service_principal {

client_id     = var.client_id

client_secret = var.client_secret
}

tags = {

Environment = var.environment
}

}
```

variables.tf

```
variable “dns_prefix” {

description = “DNS prefix”

}

variable “location” {

description = “azure location to deploy resources”

}

variable “cluster_name” {

description = “AKS cluster name”

}

variable “name” {

description = “name of the resource group to deploy AKS cluster in”

}

variable “kubernetes_version” {

description = “version of the kubernetes cluster”

}

variable “agent_pool_name” {

description = “name for the agent pool profile”

default = “agentpool”

}

variable “agent_pool_type” {

description = “type of the agent pool (AvailabilitySet and VirtualMachineScaleSets)”

default = “VirtualMachineScaleSets”

}

variable “node_count” {

description = “number of nodes to deploy”

}

variable “vm_size” {

description = “size/type of VM to use for nodes”

}

variable “vnet_subnet_id” {

description = “vnet id where the nodes will be deployed”

}

variable “network_plugin” {

description = “network plugin for kubenretes network overlay (azure or calico)”

}

variable “service_cidr” {

description = “kubernetes internal service cidr range”

}

variable “client_id” {

description = “Service principle Client Id”

}

variable “client_secret” {

description = “Service principle Client Secret”

}

variable “min_count” {

description = “Minimum Node Count”

}

variable “max_count” {

description = “Maximum Node Count”

}

variable “default_pool_name” {

description = “name for the agent pool profile”

default = “agentpool”

}

variable “default_pool_type” {

description = “type of the agent pool (AvailabilitySet and VirtualMachineScaleSets)”

default = “VirtualMachineScaleSets”

}

variable “environment” {

description = “Environment”

}
```

there is no such variable "subnet_id" in the aks-cluster module so removed the subnet_id in  aks_cluster after removing showing the below error

Unsupported block type in aks-cluster folder main.tf inside it Blocks of type ingress_application_gateway are not expected here.

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody else gets to this page when searching for this error message. We fixed the error "Blocks of type ingress_application_gateway are not expected here" by upgrading terraform provider azurerm from version 2.43 to 2.73

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>2.73.0"
    }
  }
}
```